# Console print statement not working in Junit test in Spring Boot microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I am trying to create Junit testing for my Spring Boot microservice. I need to see the response or result from the performed operation. When I am adding like this, it's not printing in my console.

```
@Test
public void retrieveDetailsForCourse() throws Exception {

    Mockito.when(
            studentService.retrieveCourse(Mockito.anyString(),
                    Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockCourse);

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
            "/students/Student1/courses/Course1").accept(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

    System.out.println(result.getResponse());

}
```

How can I retrieve the response/result from the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `andDo(print())` to print the request and response to console, for example:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
   .andDo(print())
   .andReturn();
```

You'll probably also want to add some assertions against the response, for example:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
   .andExpect(status().isOk())
   .andExpect(content().contentType(...))
   .andExpect(content().string("..."));
```

That's the standard approach with MockMvc testing but it's possible that there's something else wrong in your test case. Using `andReturn()` along with `result.getResponse().getContentAsString()` *should* print out the response so if you're seeing nothing printed then either:

- The response is empty
- The `perform()` call has thrown an exception thereby causing an exit before your `System.out` call.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your response. And how to check the retrieving is integer instead of .andExpect(content().string("")) ? Is there any integer checking method available?

Comment: An integer is coercible to a String so if you expect an integer with the value `100` then this assertion will suceed: `.andExpect(content().string("100"))`